# Bootstrap - Hide as screen width reduces (rather than drop to next row)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

On large screens I have a row of boxes, as the screen width narrows the boxes tuck down underneath one by one:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m1aec0ov/

But I only ever want to show the top row of boxes. So instead of the boxes **dropping down** underneath, I'm trying to have them **disappear** instead. Is there nothing which will automatically take care of this?

It's been suggested I use hidden-xs or d-block (Bootstrap 4) classes to make the boxes disappear, but this would require me to calculate the position of each box and apply the correct screen size class.

This feels strange because Bootstrap has already done the hard work - it already knows when a box should tuck underneath. Is it not possible to simply say, "hide rather than tuck underneath"?

Comment: give the container, you wish to hide an id and hide it when nessesary...?

Comment: This would require me to calculate when the box should be hidden, which is odd as nothing was required to calculate when a box should drop beneath (need the exact same detection logic, but different outcome).

Comment: Ooh yeah, i see... Sorry, i couldn't help...

Comment: Is this bootstrap 3 or 4 ?

Comment: Either can be used if one has an easier solution.

Comment: In bootstrap 3 you can use class `hidden-xs` in 4 use  `.d-none .d-sm-block`

Comment: True but as mentioned in the question, I would still need to go and calculate which box should be allocated which sizing class.

Comment: aah i see, they may have different widths, sorry didn't catch that

Comment: Just to clarify each box would always have the same width, but of course screen widths would vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set you `container` to have `max-height` equal to height of element inside and set `overflow: hidden;` on it

For example:

```css
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 5px;
}

/* max-height - height of child (.box) element + margin */
.container {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Simple and effective - great shout.